# Access node in Adobe CEP extension

Tags: node.js, adobe-extension

Adobe allows usage of Node.js in CEP extensions, if activated through the manifest.xml. I followed all steps and tried to reproduce this example from Davide Barranca:
http://www.davidebarranca.com/2017/10/html-panel-tips-25-cc-2018-survival-guide/#comment-202966

But cep_node just stays undefined, whatever I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already solved it myself through the manifest. Make sure that
1. The tag  and  have the attribute Version="7.0"
2. Make sure the required  tag with its child is within the  tag. In some Adobe example it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for more detailed information on working with Node.js in a CEP extension, a frequently overlooked step is to enable Node.js in the `manifest.xml` file:

```
    <CEFCommandLine>
      <Parameter>--enable-nodejs</Parameter>
    </CEFCommandLine>
```

A full manifest depends on your desired setup and can get long, but [here's one example](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/blob/master/CEP_HTML_Test_Extension/CSXS/manifest.xml).

---

A few resources to learn more:

1. The new [CEP Getting Started guide](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides) covers writing a basic manifest.

   - Even if you're using CEP 8.0, you'll need to have the `Version="7.0"` attribute for the `ExtensionManifest` and `RequiredRuntime` elements.
   - See the [sample manifest](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides#2-configure-your-extension-in-manifestxml) in this Getting Started guide.
2. The [CEP Cookbook has some deeper info on writing a manifest file](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_8.x/Documentation/CEP%208.0%20HTML%20Extension%20Cookbook.md#extension-manifest).
3. We've recently updated the samples in the [CEP Samples repo](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples).

   - [This sample](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/tree/master/CEP_HTML_Test_Extension) will give you some further insight into how to use Node.js.
4. [We've got a blog post up](https://medium.com/adobetech/how-to-build-a-node-js-server-in-a-panel-ba1d63ea67e2) that walks you through a more complex setup with Node.js.